# call php function when button is clicked

Tags: php

i have a form..when i click the insert button the values has to be store in database..
but in my form when i open the form the default values are storing in db.i am developing all these in php mvc architecture.

this is my controller:

```
 <?php
        class ControllerSaleAd extends Controller {
private $error = array();

         public function index() {

    $this->load->language('sale/ad');


    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));


$this->data['heading_title']=$this->language->get('heading_title');
$this->data['entry_customer_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_customer_name');
$this->data['column_name']=$this->language->get('column_name');
$this->data['column_place'] = $this->language->get('column_place');
$this->data['column_date'] = $this->language->get('column_date');

$this->data['column_units'] = $this->language->get('column_units');
$this->data['column_price'] = $this->language->get('column_price');
$this->data['button_insert'] = $this->language->get('button_insert');


$this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

$this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('sale/ad', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
);

$url='';
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('sale/ad', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');

$this->template='sale/ad.tpl';
$this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
);


$this->load->model('sale/ad');






$this->insert();

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
      }

public function insert() {



    $customer = $_POST['entry_customer_name'];
    $adtype = $_POST['column_name'];
    $adplace=$_POST['column_place'];
    $date=$_POST['column_date'];
    $units=$_POST['column_units'];
    $price=$_POST['column_price'];


    $data=array();

    $data = array (

     'customer' => $customer,
     'adtype'  =>  $adtype,
     'adplace'  => $adplace,
     'date'     => $date,
     'units'    => $units,
     'price'    => $price,
    );


$this->model_sale_ad->insert($data);
    }

}




      ?>
```

when i click the insert button the insert() function has to be called....
help me how to write like that...

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas seem to be a bit confused. You can't run PHP code on client-side (ie: when a user click a button)

What you can do is an AJAX call to your php page that will insert your records.
Many of current frameworks have libs to manage AJAX action easly.

You can read further here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)